# How to reference an UI element from ViewModel (WPF)?

Tags: c#, wpf

This might be simple for you guys but am just starting in WPF, and always my mind thinks in terms of Winforms, and am wrong all the time.

Anyway here is my situation.  I have label in my view like below:

```
UserControl

 <UserControl.Resources>

    <Converters:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="visibilityConverter"></Converters:BooleanToVisibilityConverter>

    <!-- Error Handling -->
    <Converters:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />

    <Converters:ErrorConverter x:Key="errorConverter"/>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ErrorTemplate">
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2">
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="textBoxInError" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors), Converter={StaticResource errorConverter}}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="comboBoxInError" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors), Converter={StaticResource errorConverter}}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Label

```
<Label Name="IsImageValid"  Content="Image Created" Margin="0,7,-1,0" Style="{StaticResource LabelField}"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="15" Width="90" Height="28" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                    Grid.Column="1" IsEnabled="True" 
                    Visibility="{Binding IsImageValid,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

I am trying to call the this label in my view model but not sure how.

I have t following method in the viewmodel, planning to use the label to display some message based on the condition like below.

```
  ViewModel

 public class MetadataViewModel : NotificationObject, IMetadataViewModel
{
    #region :: Properties ::

    private IEventAggregator eventAggregator;
    private IImageResizerService imageResizer;

    private string headerInfo;
    public string HeaderInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return headerInfo;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.headerInfo != value)
            {
                this.headerInfo = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.HeaderInfo);
            }
        }
    }

    public ICommand SaveCommand
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public ICommand CloseCommand
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public ICommand DeleteCommand
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public ICommand SubmitCommand
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public ICommand UnSubmitCommand
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public ICommand LocationSearchCommand
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public ICommand SubjectSearchCommand
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public ICommand RemoveLocationCommand
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public ICommand RemoveSubjectCommand
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    private StoryItem selectedStory;
    public StoryItem SelectedStory
    {
        get
        {
            return this.selectedStory;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.selectedStory != value)
            {
                this.selectedStory = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.SelectedStory);

                // raise dependencies
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.CanSave);
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.CanUnSubmit);
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.CanDelete);

            }
        }
    }


    public List<Program> ProgramList 
    { 
        get; 
        private set; 
    }

    public List<Genre> GenreList 
    { 
        get; 
        private set; 
    }

    public List<Copyright> CopyrightList 
    { 
        get; 
        private set; 
    }

    public bool CanSave
    {
        get
        {
            bool canSave = false;

            if (this.SelectedStory.IsLockAvailable)
            {
                if (!this.SelectedStory.Submitted)
                {
                    canSave = true;
                }
            }

            return canSave;
        }
    }

    public bool CanDelete
    {
        get
        {
            bool canDelete = false;

            if (this.SelectedStory.IsLockAvailable)
            {
                if (!this.SelectedStory.Submitted)
                {
                    canDelete = true;
                }
            }

            return canDelete;
        }
    }



    public bool CanUnSubmit
    {
        get
        {
            bool canUnSubmit = false;

            if (this.SelectedStory.IsLockAvailable)
            {
                if (this.SelectedStory.Submitted)
                {
                    canUnSubmit = true;
                }
            }

            return canUnSubmit;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region :: Contructor ::

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MetadataViewModel(
            IMetadataController metadataController, 
            IGatewayService gateway, 
            INavigationService navigator,
            IImageResizerService imageResizer,
            IEventAggregator eventAggregator
        )
    {
        this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        this.imageResizer = imageResizer;

        // populate drop-down lists
        this.ProgramList = gateway.GetPrograms(true);
        this.GenreList = gateway.GetGenres();
        this.CopyrightList = gateway.GetCopyrights();

        // add dummy values so the user can de-select
        this.ProgramList.Add(new Program());
        this.GenreList.Add(new Genre());
        this.CopyrightList.Add(new Copyright());

        // commands
        this.SaveCommand = metadataController.SaveCommand;
        this.CloseCommand = metadataController.CloseCommand;
        this.DeleteCommand = metadataController.DeleteCommand;
        this.SubmitCommand = metadataController.SubmitCommand;
        this.UnSubmitCommand = metadataController.UnSubmitCommand;



        this.LocationSearchCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(this.LocationSearch);
        this.SubjectSearchCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(this.SubjectSearch);
        this.RemoveLocationCommand = new DelegateCommand<Topic>(this.RemoveLocation);
        this.RemoveSubjectCommand = new DelegateCommand<Topic>(this.RemoveSubject);

        // events
        this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<StorySelectedEvent>().Subscribe(OnStorySelected, ThreadOption.UIThread);
        this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<AddLocationEvent>().Subscribe(OnAddLocation, ThreadOption.UIThread);
        this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<AddSubjectEvent>().Subscribe(OnAddSubject, ThreadOption.UIThread);
        this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<CommandCompletedEvent>().Subscribe(OnCommandCompleted, ThreadOption.UIThread);
        this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<ImageResizeCompletedEvent>().Subscribe(OnImageResizeCompleted, ThreadOption.UIThread);

        this.Initialize();
    }

    #endregion

    private void OnStorySelected(StoryItem selectedStory)
    {
        if (this.selectedStory != null)
        {
            this.Initialize();

            // override the initialized values
            this.SelectedStory = selectedStory;
            this.SelectedStory.HaveChanged = false;
            this.HeaderInfo = "Edit";
        }
    }

    public void OnAddLocation(Topic topic)
    {
        if (topic != null)
        {
            if (!this.SelectedStory.Locations.Contains(topic))
            {
                this.SelectedStory.Locations.Add(topic);
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.SelectedStory.Locations);
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnAddSubject(Topic topic)
    {
        if (topic != null)
        {
            if (!this.SelectedStory.Subjects.Contains(topic))
            {
                this.SelectedStory.Subjects.Add(topic);
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.SelectedStory.Subjects);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnCommandCompleted(string commandType)
    {
        if (commandType == CommandTypes.MetadataEntry)
        {
            this.Initialize();
        }
    }

    private void OnImageResizeCompleted(bool isSuccessful)
    {
        IsImageValid = false;
        if (isSuccessful)
        {

            this.SelectedStory.KeyframeImages = true;
            IsImageValid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            this.SelectedStory.KeyframeImages = false;
            IsImageValid=false;
        }
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        this.SelectedStory = new StoryItem();
        this.HeaderInfo = "Create";
    }

    private void LocationSearch(object topicType)
    {
        this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<LocationSearchEvent>().Publish(null);
    }

    private void SubjectSearch(object topicType)
    {
        this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<SubjectSearchEvent>().Publish(null);
    }

    private void RemoveLocation(Topic selected)
    {
        if (selected != null)
        {
            // remove the primary too
            if (this.SelectedStory.PrimaryLocation != null)
            {
                if (string.Equals(this.SelectedStory.PrimaryLocation.FullName, selected.FullName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    this.SelectedStory.PrimaryLocation = new Topic();
                }
            }

            bool isSuccessful = this.SelectedStory.Locations.Remove(selected);
            if (isSuccessful)
            {
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.SelectedStory.Locations);
            }
        }
    }

    private void RemoveSubject(Topic selected)
    {
        if (selected != null)
        {
            // remove the primary too
            if (this.SelectedStory.PrimarySubject != null)
            {
                if (string.Equals(this.SelectedStory.PrimarySubject.FullName, selected.FullName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    this.SelectedStory.PrimarySubject = new Topic();
                }
            }

            bool isSuccessful = this.SelectedStory.Subjects.Remove(selected);
            if (isSuccessful)
            {
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.SelectedStory.Subjects);
            }
        }
    }
}

        private booly _isImageValid;

        public bool IsImageValid
        {
        get
        { 
            return _isImageValid;
        }
        set
        {
            _isImageValid = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.IsImageValid);
        }
    }
}
```

Honestly i don't know how view will understand the binding.

Comment: This won't ever work. Have you set the DataContext of your view to your ViewModel? Have you implemented **INotifyProperty** Changed interface in your VM or inherited VM from a model that implemets InotifyPropertyChanged? IsImageValid needs to be a public property and not a variable in a member function. Also, in the **setter of the IsImageValid**, you need to call the **PropertyChanged** Method and pass the name of the property. Also, instead of using bool IsImageValid, you can directly bind with **System.Windows.Visibility IsImageValid**. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: @Shakit Singh,thanks and appreciate all your help,seriously just fixing some ones code so please bear with me.

Comment: Added the whole view model class for your view,can you please point to where i have to make changes please

Comment: **IsImageValid** is not a property in your VM. It should be a property, and in setter you call your **RaisePropertyChanged()** method. Have a look at the answer that I have posted to this question. Let me know your doubt. I have used a Visibility property in my answer to avoid using a converter. You can use either of it.

Comment: I made changes to my answer having a look at your VM.

Comment: Added Code to your VM, at the end and modified your **OnImageResizeCompleted()** method. Have a look, it should work.

Comment: already made the changes in my VM but still have some issues with View and xaml.cs file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10998/discussion-between-usher-and-shakti-singh)

Comment: Are the other properties binding correctly to the View from VM? Are you getting some exception? are you sure the Converter is correctly wirtten? If you think there could be a problem with Converter, use Visibility type for IsImageValid rather than bool and bind directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A standard approach is to have a boolean property like "IsImageValid" in your ViewModel...Then in your XAML, bind the Visibility property of your label to that property, with a BooleanToVisibilityConverter http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <BooleanToVisibilityConverter
         x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
Then use it in one or more bindings like this:

<Label Visibility="{Binding IsImageValid, 
       Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" 
   ......... />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for quick suggestion but i don't even see the view in my view model.

Comment: I tried exactly what you suggested but it doesn't look like working or am still missing something in my end. Updated OP with your suggestion can you please guide me.

Answer (score 3):

please read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) post first.

If you wanna display some text in your Label then your have to do the following steps:

- add a **Property** to your Viewmodel
- implement **INotifyPropertyChanged** in your Viewmodel and raise the event when ever the Property change
- in your view set the **DataContext** to your Viewmodel instance
- create a **Binding** in xaml to your property

thats all ;)

Comment: Honestly,MVVM looks really tough to me ,if i compare with Win forms.This is matter of sec i can do in winforms.God help me!.Thanks for your help blindmeis

Comment: forget winforms if you wanna do wpf ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to see View from ViewModel, it is a basic principle behind MVVM pattern. View knows about VM, whereas VM does not know about View. Instead, you can do as @JeffN825 suggested, at least I'd recommend this as well.

Comment: No, that's how it is in MVC. In MVVM, communication between the View and ViewModel is bidirectional. It's the Model that has no connection to or knowledge of the view.

Comment: @phoff the communication is indeed bi-directional, however it is done "under the hood"  and you just set DataContext to your view model in the view. From programmers perspective the view-model knows nothing about the view. In other words you don't reference the view in your view-model code.

Answer (score -1):

Add the following to your user Control Property:

```
xmlns:VM="clr-namespace:<ProjectName>.ViewModels" //this place throws exception,what is <ProjectName> ?
```

For assigning the DataContext to the User Control use the following code if the DataContext is not already assigned:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>     //where to add this part ?  
    <VM:MyViewModel>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Bind the Visibility of the label in the following manner:

```
Visibility="{Binding IsImageValid}"   //this is done
```

Your ViewModel or ViewModelBase from which the VM is inherited should implement the **INotifyPropertyChanged** Interface:

```
namespace MyApp.ViewModels           //this i have to do it at xaml.cs file  or suppose to be in viewmodel ?
{
    public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {...
     ...
    }
}
```

Declare the data member and Property in your VM like this:

```
private System.Windows.Visibility _isImageValid; //add this code in my viewmodel

public System.Windows.Visibility IsImageValid
{
    get
    { 
        return _isImageValid;
    }
    set
    {
        _isImageValid = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.IsImageValid);
    }
}
```

Comment: am not sure how to add the file here,otherwise i will attached and pin point the exceptions